# show f is differentiable at c if and only if there exists a function g on I that is continuous at c and satisfies f(x) − f(c) = g(x)(x − c) ∀x ∈ I.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let f be defined on an interval I containing the point c. Then f is differentiable at c if and only if there exists a function g on I that is continuous at c and satisfies
f(x) − f(c) = g(x)(x − c) ∀x ∈ I.
In this case1, we have g(c) = f'(c).

1This result is also known as Caratheodory’s Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ to be differentiable at $c$. Define $g:I\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ for $x\ne c$ and $g(c)=f'(c)$. By the definition of the derivative $g$ is continuous at $c$ and it is clear that we have $f(x)-f(c)=g(x)(x-c)$.

Now assume there is such a function $g$. Then for $x\ne c$ we have:$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=g(x)$$
Since $g$ is continuous at $c$ the limit $x\to c$ of the left side exists. But this precisely means that $f$ is differentiable at $c$.